# UI in in IOS simulator doesn't show

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, ios-simulator, xcode4.2

I have a question I am trying to create a database from a tutorial that I have posted on here. The problem that I keep having is that when I build the project the project is built successfully. However when the IOS simulator pulls up to show me the UI I have a black screen. I have doubled checked that my connections to my storyboards are correct. and still my UI still not displaying. I have made sure that I had my sqlite library connected within the project and it is. This is a single view application for an IPAD. I have searched ways of finding issues within my code and I have done breakpoints to see where my application breaks. and This is what I have found. 
[image]

this is where my application breaks because is the first screen that it pops after I have started the IOS simulator. I do not know how to fix this.

[image]
this screen basically tells me that there is something wrong with the UIwindow alloc. For some reason is breaking here and I do not know why.

[image]
This last screen shot is not that great to interpret especially if its in numbers.

Please help. I will be posting more screen shots if needed at this point I need all the help that I can get. I did not think that it would be difficult to create and link a db.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using storyboards you need to remove all the code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and just return YES. Also set your main storyboard file appropriately in the plist file.

Comment: Sorry to ask I am new to the xcode environment. Where is the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions?

Comment: This is in the AppDelegate.m file. You can see the method in the second screenshot you posted. Erase all the code in that mode up until "return YES;"